# Are these rules valid for reactjs architure level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, redux

I am currently working on one reactjs web application. The architect has already setup React-Redux in the application. Now as a developer me and my teammate, we are working on the different areas of the application. So there are certain guidelines that the Architect has given to us:

1. Our merge requests should be independent of each other. Meaning, we will keep creating merge requests and he will merge it in any order. He will not follow the merge request sequence. I find it strange.
2. Secondly, he wants us to create react components without using internal state(mostly functional/stupid components). We are kind of prohibited (exceptionally, somewhere he may allow) to do `this.state = {}` in a component if it would be a stateful one. Mostly we need to strict to the fact that we can have mostly functional components but not the stateful component and there will be only one store that is a redux store. Other than that no internal state. One app with only one state.

I do not understand these rules. I mean 
1 - If our code will not go on dev branch properly (sequentially to be precise) so how can we share our code amongst each other and do progress? 
2 - If we listen to him and accept the principle that one app can have only one state no other internal state then, what other people teach in tutorials (online, in articles) is that wrong ?

I am bit confuse. Are these valid rules to follow ?

Comment: I think this would be better asked on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Other than that, my personal opinion is that there are no absolutes in development. The architect on your team probably tells your team not to do things to avoid abuse, but he will surely listen if you have a good use-case or he'll probably be happy to explain the reasoning behind his rules.

Comment: Also, you're asking 2 unrelated questions, which is "prohibited" on the stack exchange network.